# With SQL Server how to get the most recent date while summing on amount and the sum of the amount is greater than 0?

Tags: sql-server

I have a transaction table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trans](
[ID] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[PersonID] [char](6) NULL,
[TransCode] [char](2) NULL,
[TransDesc] [char](45) NULL,
[TransDate] [datetime] NULL,
[TransAmount] [numeric](18, 2) NULL)
```

What I want is the date and amount of the most recent payment made by each person.  Payments are defined by the TransCode (see the WHERE clause below).

There can be multiple transactions on any given day, so I want the sum of transactions on the most recent day.  Also there can be "reversal" transactions that could make the sum of the transactions on the most recent day be 0 (zero) -- I don't want these to be in the results (hence the "HAVING   (SUM(TransAmount) > 0)" below).

Here is my most recent attempt, that is not working, but I don't know why!

```
SELECT  PersonID, MAX(TransDate) AS LastPaymentDate, TotalAmount  
FROM    (SELECT   PersonID, TransDate, SUM(TransAmount) AS TotalAmount
         FROM     Trans
         WHERE    (TransCode IN ('11', '12', '13', '14', '18', '19', '61', '63', '68', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '78', '79', '80', '81', '94', 'P2'))
         GROUP BY PersonID, TransDate
         HAVING   (SUM(TransAmount) > 0)
         ORDER BY PersonID, TransDate) AS TotalAmount
GROUP BY PersonID, TotalAmount
ORDER BY PersonID
```

When I run the inner query I get what expect, a list of amounts summed by date, for each person.  The outer query though, for some reason, is returning multiple rows for each person.  It should only return one row for each person :-(

Can someone one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Please let me know if there is any additional information you may need to understand the problem better.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide,

Ben

Comment: First change the name of the inner Select to something other than 'TotalAmount'  it's kind of confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  LastDate.PersonID, LastDate.TransDate AS LastPaymentDate, TotalAmount.TotalAmount  
FROM    (SELECT   PersonID, Max(TransDate) as TransDate
         FROM     Trans
         WHERE    (TransCode IN ('11', '12', '13', '14', '18', '19', '61', '63', '68', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '78', '79', '80', '81', '94', 'P2'))
         GROUP BY PersonID
         HAVING   (SUM(TransAmount) > 0)
         ORDER BY PersonID, TransDate) AS LastDate
INNER JOIN (SELECT PersonID, Transdate, SUM(TransAMount) as TotalAmount 
         FROM     Trans
         WHERE    (TransCode IN ('11', '12', '13', '14', '18', '19', '61', '63', '68', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '78', '79', '80', '81', '94', 'P2'))
         GROUP BY PersonID
         HAVING   (SUM(TransAmount) > 0)
         ORDER BY PersonID, TransDate) AS TotalAmount 
ON TotalAmount.PersonID = LastDate.PersonID AND TotalAmount.TransDate = LastDate.TransDate
ORDER BY LastDate.PersonID
```

Something like that should work

Comment: After getting it to actually run by removing the inner select Order by's and adding the transdate to the group by of the second inner select, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try windowing functions which may be more efficient - This shouls work .

```
select personid,trandate,SUM(transamount) as total 
from(
select personid,
CAST(transdate as DATE) as Trandate,transamount,
RANK() over(partition by personid order by
 CAST(transdate as DATE) desc) as rnk
 from trans
 ) as x
 where rnk=1
 group by PersonID,trandate
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting multiple rows since you're grouping by PersonId and TotalAmount, and there are multiple dates with the same TotalAmount.

Just wrap the entire SQL you have in another select to grab the MAX(LastPaymentDate):

```
SELECT PersonID, LastPaymentDate, TotalAmount  FROM (
SELECT  PersonID, MAX(TransDate) AS LastPaymentDate, TotalAmount  
FROM    (SELECT   PersonID, TransDate, SUM(TransAmount) AS TotalAmount
         FROM     Trans
         WHERE    (TransCode IN ('11', '12', '13', '14', '18', '19', '61', '63', 
'68', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '78', '79', '80', '81', '94', 'P2'))
         GROUP BY PersonID, TransDate
         HAVING   (SUM(TransAmount) > 0)
         ORDER BY PersonID, TransDate) AS InnerSelect
GROUP BY PersonID, TotalAmount
ORDER BY PersonID
) 
GROUP BY PersonID, LastPaymentDate, TotalAmount  
HAVING LastPaymentDate = MAX(LastPaymentDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work nice (but I didn't test it.)

```
WITH PersonDateSum AS
(
  SELECT   PersonID, TransDate, SUM(TransAmount) AS TotalAmount
         FROM     Trans
         WHERE    (TransCode IN ('11', '12', '13', '14', '18', '19', '61', '63', '68', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '78', '79', '80', '81', '94', 'P2'))
         GROUP BY PersonID, TransDate
         HAVING   (SUM(TransAmount) > 0)
         ORDER BY PersonID, TransDate
) 
SELECT PersonID, LastPaymentDate, TotalAmount
FROM PersonDateSum
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY PersonID, LastPaymentDate ORDER BY PersonID, LastPaymentDate DESC) = 1
ORDER BY PersonID
```

If you are having speed issues I suggest you put your trans code select items in a table and join on it, it will be faster than using the IN statement.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try... looks interesting.  I've used some of the things you used, like "OVER" and "PARTITION BY".

Comment: LOL... That should read: "I'll have to give that a try... looks interesting. I've *never* used some of the things you used, like "OVER" and "PARTITION BY""  That was an important word to miss ;-)

Comment: Let me know how it goes -- in theory you should be able to get rid of the sub-query with it, but it was the end of the day....